# How many tasks can a celery worker process execute simultaneously

Tags: celery, file-descriptor

I have a celery application where a task involves making an API call, then opening a file, writing into that file API response, and finally closing that file. When I run with a lot of tasks bombarded at it, I find that the number of open file descriptors for this one worker process reaches 130, as long as the load is there.

I have used the default configurations. I understand that writing part can probably be optimized, but the reason I did this experiment was to find out how many tasks a celery worker process can pick up at a time. Any clues why such high number of tasks (130) are being picked?

Comment: Is the writing opening reading and closing all one task or is it serrate tasks?

Comment: writing, reading all happens within one task.